# Making a custom grid in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code:

```
  val  itemSize = buttonTexts.size
    var  position = 0

    for  (i in  0  until itemSize) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                for (j in 0 until 3) {
                    if (position.inc() <= itemSize) {

                            MusuButton(buttonText = buttonTexts[i]) { checkCorrect(it) }

                    }

                }
            
                }
        }
    }
```

Problem is I get the same text in the buttons 3 times which makes sense because of the loop. What I am trying to do is have a multiple rows of 3 buttons for however many items are in buttonTexts and use each text for the buttons text

Comment: Your problem was just incorrect counter usage, this question/answer is not gonna help anyone, who would search for this question title.

Comment: So everything looks OK now? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by changing the following.

MusuButton(buttonText = buttonTexts[position++) { checkCorrect(it) }